# How to use Union method or left outer join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i can not join #Temp with scr_SecuristLog. How can i do it?

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (VisitingCount int, [Time] int )
 DECLARE @DateNow DATETIME,@i int,@Time int
    set @DateNow='00:00'  
    set @i=1;  
    while(@i<48)  
        begin  
set @DateNow = DATEADD(minute, 30, @DateNow)
set @Time = (datepart(hour,@DateNow)*60+datepart(minute,@DateNow))/30 
insert into #Temp(VisitingCount,[Time]) values(0,@Time )
set @i=@i+1
                end
select VisitingCount, [Time]
from #Temp as t
left outer join (
    select count(page) as VisitingCount, 
    (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30 as [Time]
    from scr_SecuristLog
    where Date between '2009-05-04' and '2009-05-05'
) as s
    on t.VisitingCount = s.VisitingCount
        and t.Time = s.Time
```

This Codes give error:

---

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'scr_SecuristLog.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'scr_SecuristLog.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'VisitingCount'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'Time'.

Answer (score 2):

As you don't mention a specific error, I am guessing your error comes from the fact you have not prefixed your select values.

```
select t.VisitingCount, t.[Time]
```

---

**Edit**

Your second error should be resolved with this group by.

```
select count(page) as VisitingCount, 
(datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30 as [Time]
from scr_SecuristLog
where Date between '2009-05-04' and '2009-05-05'
GROUP BY (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a GROUP BY in your derived table scr_SecuristLog, you need to group it by time because your using an aggregate function count.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
  VisitingCount INT,
  [Time] INT)
DECLARE @DateNow DATETIME,
  @i INT,
  @Time INT
SET @DateNow = '00:00'

SET @i = 1 ;

WHILE(@i < 48)

  BEGIN

    SET @DateNow = DATEADD(minute, 30, @DateNow)
    SET @Time = (DATEPART(hour, @DateNow) * 60 + DATEPART(minute, @DateNow))
      / 30 
    INSERT  INTO #Temp (VisitingCount, [Time])
    VALUES  (0, @Time)
    SET @i = @i + 1
  END
SELECT  VisitingCount,
        [Time]
FROM    #Temp AS t
UNION
SELECT  COUNT(page) AS VisitingCount,
        (DATEPART(hour, Date) * 60 + DATEPART(minute, Date)) / 30 AS [Time]
FROM    scr_SecuristLog
WHERE   Date BETWEEN '2009-05-04' AND '2009-05-05'
GROUP BY Date
```

DROP TABLE #Temp

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (VisitingCount int, [Time] int )
DECLARE @DateNow DATETIME,@i int,@Time int
set @DateNow='00:00'  
set @i=1;  
while(@i<48)  
    begin  
        set @DateNow = DATEADD(minute, 30, @DateNow)
        set @Time = (datepart(hour,@DateNow)*60+datepart(minute,@DateNow))/30 
        insert into #Temp(VisitingCount,[Time]) values(0,@Time )
        set @i=@i+1
    end
    select t.VisitingCount, t.[Time]
    from #Temp as t
    left outer join (
         select count(page) as VisitingCount, 
       (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30 as [Time]
       from scr_SecuristLog
       where Date between '2009-05-04' and '2009-05-05'
       GROUP BY scr_SecuristLog.Date
   ) as s
    on t.VisitingCount = s.VisitingCount
    and t.Time = s.Time
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner select (which you are joining on) does not aggregate properly. You have a count and a column. This means you need to group by the column for SQL to understand it properly.

```
select t.VisitingCount, t.[Time]
from #Temp as t
left outer join (
    select count(page) as VisitingCount, 
    (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30 as [Time]
    from scr_SecuristLog
    where Date between '2009-05-04' and '2009-05-05'
    GROUP BY [Date]
) as s
    on t.VisitingCount = s.VisitingCount
        and t.Time = s.Time
```

What you might actually need is to group by the calculated column instead, in which case your group by should be:

```
GROUP BY (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30
```